# Postgres DELETE FROM not deleting rows but returning success

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i try to delete rows from a table, it does not work. 
I used the standard DELETE FROM statement, using tag_id=1
The first statement is returning Success, so i expect that the rows are deleted.
However, the rows are not deleted. And i can't seem to figure out why.

- What could be the cause of this?

The image below has the specific query statements, and the return result.

[image]

Comment: Do you have delete privilige on the table?

Comment: When you do the delete, does it tell you how many rows were affected?

Comment: Is autocommit on?  Is it possible that you deleted, rolled back, and then selected?

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities:

- There is a trigger on the table that prevents the rows from being deleted.

  Have a look at

  ```
  \d project_tag
  ```
- Your index is corrupted. Try

  ```
  REINDEX TABLE project_tag;
  ```

Comment: Notably for triggers, ensure that you are not returning `NULL` from the `DELETE`, which is the condition for it to skip the operation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/trigger-definition.html I did that with an accidental `RETURN NEW` instead of `RETURN OLD`.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was different (in that the DELETE appeared to have worked), but this question was the number one search result and phrased exactly like my issue. I want to say:

AUTOCOMMIT

Some DB connections have autocommit as an option during their connection profile. Checking that solved my issue.

Comment: Agree, am using SQLAlchemy python and I set the `autocommit=False`, hence, I have to call `session.commit()` to make it executed against the database.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers work, I would recommend trying `explain` on the delete query. In my case it turned out to be a faulty RLS policy (more details below). The output of `explain` showed a suspicious `Filter: (false AND (id='...'::uuid))`, where, the `false` was being introduced by the RLS policy.

Details about RLS fault: I had included only a single policy for delete and it was a `restrictive` policy. After carefully reading the RLS docs, I found out that there must be at least one `permissive` policy for the `restrictive` policies to make sense. If not, then no records will be accessible.

- Docs for explain: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html
- Docs for RLS: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ddl-rowsecurity.html